# SSD sometimes not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a weird issue... I have a secondary SSD (in /dev/sdb). Sometimes (after a reboot or just when the disk feels like it), the system can not recognize it and /dev/sdb does not exist and does not show up in `/proc/partitions` or when I run `lsblk`.
The only way to get the disk back is to do a shutdown and then power on again. Reboot does nothing.

I did try to scan with `echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host[N]/scan` (where [N] is a number), but to no avail..

**UPDATE:**
After some help here, did some investigation and ran `sudo journalctl -b 0`

*(Also removed redundant comments)*

**After a reboot**

`kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)`

`kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)`

**After shutdown and immediately power on**

`kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)`

`kernel: ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)`

**running `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`**

`9 Power_On_Hours - 0x0032 - 100 - 100 - 000 - Old_age - Always - 807`

I wonder; why does it detect the disk on reboot but when powered off?

Comment: The drive and or its connection to the main board is bad and or lose.

Comment: @David I checked the cable and it looked fine, but of course, that is not a guarantee.. Is there any way to force the system to try and detect disks?

Comment: __1__ Look at the system logs for a hint: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /dev/sdb`. You can look at previous boots by varying the `-b` number `-b -1` for previous boot, `-b -2` for the one before that, etc. `sudo journalctl  --list-boots` will help you pick. Read `man journalctl`. __2__ Also, wiggle the cable while testing. __3__ Read `man smartctl` to access the disk's internal stats.

Comment: That's logvomit, a no-no. It's accessed via a link, which is unreliable. It's in a Comment, which isn't indexed (like Qs and As). Read it yourself, find anomalies, [edit] your Question to add data and refine your Question. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: @waltinator Question updated. Thank you for being patient :)